# How to map an entity in Entity Framework Core that has primary key but is a value object in the domain model?

Tags: entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

I have this model in my domain:

```
pubilc class Order
{
    long Id;

    Address DeliveryAddress;
}

public class Address
{
    string Street;
    string PostalCode;
    string City;
    string Country;
}
```

But in my database I have a table for address with and ID, that is the `CustomerAddresses`:

```
CustomerAddresses
(
     Id, IDCustomer, Street, PostalCode, City, Country
);
```

My repository map the classes of the domain model in the configuration of the context.

But in this case, I don't know how to map it, because I don't want that when I add a new order, EF Core could try to add a new address.

I don't know if I should map the address as a owned entity of the order. But in this case, how could know EF Core the ID of the address of the customer?

I could add a property for the ID in the class of the domain, but in this case I would make the domain be affected by the repository layer, and I would avoid that.

But really I don't know how could I do it.

Thanks so much.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you detail the example? Show entity class and db tables?

Comment: Hello. The table in the database is CustomerAddresses(Id, IDCustomer, Street, PostalCode...). About the entities, do you mean the entities of the repository or the entities of the domain model?

Comment: The entities of the repository.